# RuntimeError: Failed to find release information: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I try to pip install a package and ran into this error:

```
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 62, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 349, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-h8d80a0v/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 31, in run
        File "/private/var/folders/r5/jxlbmztj4kd80r9_cyqkrqqm0000gn/T/pip-install-iavowyjv/chromedriver-binary-auto_df5d9f2e732743d5933cddba52c8f8a4/chromedriver_binary/utils.py", line 100, in get_latest_release_for_version
          raise RuntimeError('Failed to find release information: {}'.format(release_url))
      RuntimeError: Failed to find release information: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for chromedriver-binary-auto
Failed to build chromedriver-binary-auto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for chromedriver-binary-auto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am using Macarm64. If there is any suggestion, please let me know, thank you!

I tried to manually install chromedrive from [here].(https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.16/) and then edit .bashprofile and provide absolute path to it by`export PATH="~Downloads/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver:$PATH"`, and still have no clues why chromedrive is not working, the same error happens.